# issues with retrieving information from form for PDO query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a form where the user selects an option from a drop down list and the results are displayed in a separate php page. However, I am encountering issues with getting the information from the form and not sure if the php is picking the value up. I use jQuery to serialize the information (there is only one variable) and have attempted to see if something is being stored using `var_dump` and `print_r` but nothing gets returned.

Any help please?

the form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="searchCModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="searchCModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Search By Course: </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form id="searchCForm" class="searchCForm">
                                            <?php

                                            include "db_conx.php";

                                            try {

                                                $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

                                                $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                                $stmt3 = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT * FROM course_details ORDER BY course_title');
                                                $stmt3->execute();
                                                $courses = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                            }

                                            catch(Exception $e)
                                            {
                                                die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
                                            }
                                            ?>

                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="course_details">Select Course:</label><p></p>
                                                <select name="course">
                                                    <option value=''>Select One</option>";
                                                    <?php foreach($courses as $course): ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $course['course_code'] ?>"><?php echo $course['course_title'] ?></option>
                                                <?php endforeach ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" class="pull-right" onclick="searchCCall();">Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

the jQuery:

```
function searchCCall() {
  var data = $('#searchCForm').serialize();
  $.post('Student_SearchCourse.php', data, function(response){

    $("#searchCForm").html(response);

    window.location.href = ('Student_SearchCourse.php');

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
}
```

the php:

```
    <?php

    include "db_conx.php";

    if 
        (!isset ($_POST['course']))
    {
        $message = 'Please select a valid course';

    }

try {

        $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

        $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $course = $_POST['course'];

        $sql = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, p.description, c.course_title FROM proposal p 
            LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code
            WHERE p.course_code = :course");

        $sql->bindParam(':course', $course, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $sql->execute();
        //$user_record_id = $sql->fetchColumn();
        print_r($course);

        $proposals = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
```

Any ideas on how I can overcome this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are doing `POST` and trying to get data as `$course = $_GET['course'];` ?

Comment: I took the liberty of closing your divs properly in the form. I don't know if you didn't copy the whole code or they just weren't properly closed.

Comment: @Andrei P. Thanks yes in the actual file the closing divs are there. I just copied the form part to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$course = $_GET['course'];
```

to

```
$course = $_POST['course'];
```

because your using post method to submit data.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="frmlogin" action="Student_SearchCourse.php">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body" >
         <!-- your form element -->
       </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" class="pull-right" >Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></button>
      </div>
       </div>
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

you can wrap your form tag inside `<div class="modal content"></div>`.
no need to use js.

Comment: I've tried POST too but didn't get anything back :/

Comment: Thanks. So it returns the course_code value now but the sql query still does not pick up that I've given it the code. I've changed the sql query to WHERE course_code = :course; but i get an integrity constraint

Comment: Oh you need to specify the table name with course_code in where clause, This seems you have course_code column in multiple table. I mean c.course_code or p.course_code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have managed to get the table to return the information using the course selected i need however the jQuery is messing it up. when i comment out the line 'window.location.href = ('Student_SearchCourse.php');' it displays the results inside the modal but when i uncomment the line it can't find the course code value :/ any ideas how i can correct it?

Comment: first tell me where you want to show your returned data. On the Modal or in the Student_SearchCourse.php file. I'm little bit confused with your requirement.

Comment: In the Student_Search_Course.php file please. i have updated the original question with the new sql code :)

Comment: Oh. than why you are using `$.post()` to post data. just change your js function like `function searchCCall(){document.getElementById("searchCForm").submit();}`.

Comment: I would need the 'POST' to send the data to the php file. The function you have given doesn't do anything once i click submit :/

Answer (score 0):

Check if php is outputting the course code to the optionvalue you can do that by viewing the page source code or check if the $.post is sending the serialized data via the web browser's console